# Create C program that runs and passes batched commands to a second C program

Tags: c

Thanks in advance for the help.

I'm relatively new to C and would like to accomplish the following task.  I have a C program that takes a series of console inputs until a termination command is given.  For example

```
./myCProg  //runs myCProg in console
do this
do that
.....
quit // terminates program
```

I have a file containing a series of commands that I would like to run in the format given above.  I would like to create a second C program that will run the C program given above and pass to it the commands in the file to speed things up.  For the most part, I know how to do this.  However, how might I run the first C program within the second and pass commands to it?

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Quite unclear question; I guessed and provided a tentative answer. Please **edit your question** to improve it (what operating system, what kind of commands, what is each command doing)

Comment: @HXSP1947 i believe fork() and the exec family of functions will accomplish what you need nicely, dbush gives a good answer using these functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second program, open the input file for reading with `open`, then `fork()`.  In the forked process, use `dup2` to duplicate the file descriptor for the input file to file descriptor 0, then use an `exec` function to call the first program.

The result is that the first program is running with the input file connected to its stdin, just as if you ran `./prog1 < input_file` from the command line.

```
int fd = open("input_file", O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1) {
    perror("open failed");
    exit(1);
}
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
    perror("fork failed");
    exit(1);
} else if (pid == 0) {
    dup2(fd, 0);
    execl("/path/to/prog1", "prog1", NULL);
    perror("exec failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: That will run the second program but how can I programmatically pass commands to it?  The second program accepts commands as user input from the terminal.

Comment: @HXSP1947 See my edit. The input file becomes the input to the first program.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(What you want to achieve is unclear; I'm just guessing; and it is operating system specific; I guess you are using Linux or some other POSIX)</sup>

It seems similar to some shell. You might take inspiration from the code of existing shells (like `bash`, `sash`, [zsh](http://zsh.org/), [fish](http://fishshell.com/)...)

Alternatively, embed some existing interpreter (like [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Lua](http://lua.org/) ...) in your top C program.

BTW, to run a command from C, consider [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) or [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html); for example, you might `popen("/bin/sh", "w")` and `fprintf` some shell commands, then `pclose`

Probably, you need to get a broad picture by reading [advanced linux programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) then see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (notably [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), ....)